# pythonのtry,exceptを用いる際にエラーごとに処理を分ける方法

Tags: python

exceptでエラーごとに処理を分けて記述するにはどのように書けばよいでしょうか。
エラー全体の集合があったとしてその場合は、except:の後に処理を記述すればいいですが、
ある特定のエラーの場合だけ違う処理を行う方法などを知りたいです。

Answer (score 3):

以下のように、`error`の後にエラーを特定して記述すれば良いはずです。

```
try:
    # Some code
except Error1:
    # Action 1
except Error2:
    # Action 2
```

Comment: この場合Error2にError1に設定していないすべてのエラーを記述することはできないでしょうか？

Comment: その場合は、最後に except: だけの節を書けば大丈夫です。
http://docs.python.jp/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions