# pythonでpass文でつぶしてあるエラーを取得する

Tags: python, python3, exception

Pythonでpassをフックすることはできますか？

```
try:
    ...
except Exception:
    pass
```

上のようなエラー処理をしている部分が多いコードがありエラーを握りつぶしてしまっています。
一つ一つ書き換えてもいいのですが、数が多く大変です。消してしまっているエラーを取得する、なにかいい方法はありますか？

Comment: 何らかのトリックを使って対応できたとしても、コードの可読性や解析のしやすさが悪くなるような気がします。可能であれば正規表現を使った一括置換をして、駄目なら面倒でも一つ一つ書き換えた方が無難かもしれませんね。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ast` パッケージを利用する方法もあるかと思います。

**pass2tb.py**

```
import sys
import ast
import astunparse

class Pass2Traceback(ast.NodeTransformer):
  trace_stmt = 'import traceback;traceback.print_exc()'

  def visit_Try(self, node):
    for h in node.handlers:
      if len(h.body) == 1 and isinstance(h.body[0], ast.Pass):
        h.body = ast.parse(self.trace_stmt).body
    return node

t = ast.parse(open(sys.argv[1], 'r').read())
Pass2Traceback().visit(t)

print(astunparse.unparse(t))
```

try ... except ノードの exception handler ブロックを書き替えています。変更されるのは `pass` のみが存在する handler だけです。

例えば、以下の様なソースコードがあるとして、

**src.py**

```
try:
  {'a': 1}['b']
  1/0
  open('not exist')
except ZeroDivisionError:
  print('Divided by zero.')
except FileNotFoundError:
  print('File not found.')
except Exception:
  pass
```

以下を実行します。

```
$ python3 pass2tb.py src.py

try:
    {
        'a': 1,
    }['b']
    (1 / 0)
    open('not exist')
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print('Divided by zero.')
except FileNotFoundError:
    print('File not found.')
except Exception:
    import traceback
    traceback.print_exc()
```

実際には別ファイルにリダイレクトして、そちらを使う方が良いかと思います。

```
$ python3 pass2tb.py src.py > modified.py
$ python3 modified.py
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "modified.py", line 5, in <module>
      }['b']
  KeyError: 'b'
```

なお、AST オブジェクトをソースコードに戻すために [An AST unparser for Python](https://github.com/simonpercivall/astunparse) を利用しています。pip コマンドなどを使って、事前にインストールしておいて下さい。

Answer (score 5):

この記事が参考になりそうです。

[pythonですべての例外をキャッチし、詳細を表示させたい。](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/6972/26370)
[pythonのtry,exceptを用いる際にエラーごとに処理を分ける方法](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/23714/26370)

変更は、複数行・複数ファイルの grep,置換 が行えるエディタで一気にやってしまうとか。
私は秀丸エディタでやってます。

---

参照先をまとめると以下になります。

> `traceback`モジュールの`print_exc()`を使えば、スタック情報も表示します。

```
except:
    traceback.print_exc()
```

> sysモジュールの`exc_info()`で現在処理中の例外を参照できます。

```
except:
    print(sys.exc_info())
```

> `traceback`の情報じゃなくて、ただ、メッセージが知りたいなら、Exceptionの`args`が使えます（tupleが返される)：
>   プラスして詳細なException種別を指定して対処を振り分ける

```
except ZeroDivisionError as e:
    print("ゼロ除算例外args:", e.args)
except Exception as e:
    print("その他例外args:", e.args)
```

> もっとキチンと対応する際の考え方
>   [Pythonでtry exceptの書き方と、エラー内容の取得方法](https://symfoware.blog.fc2.com/blog-entry-873.html)